# 301 redirect not working with sub page

Tags: .htaccess

I've setup some 301 redirects in my .htaccess file.

```
 Redirect 301 /accounts http://www.domain.com/priority-accounts/
 Redirect 301 /accounts/benefits http://www.domain.com/priority-accounts/
```

The first one redirect to /priority-accounts/ as expected but the second redirects to /priority-accounts/benefits.

Why is this? I just want the second redirect to go to /priority-accounts/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works if I use

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/accounts/benefits$ http://www.domain.com/priority-accounts/
```

But only without the trailing '/'

Do I have to write another one with the trailing '/'? like this?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/accounts/benefits/$ http://www.domain.com/priority-accounts/
```

Surely there's a better way?